# Binary Search cannot find the first value in the array list

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search

I have figured out as I am always looking to see if the value is equal to the midpoint and the value is the first value it will never be true, so how does binary search manage to find the first element in an array?

```java
private int date_searcher(String date, ArrayList all_dates) {
    found = false;
    int mid_point = 0;
    int first_index = 0;
    int last_index = all_dates.size() - 1;

    try {
        find_date_parse = date_format.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        warning_disp.setText("Please input a date in the valid format");
        validation = false;
    }

    while (first_index <= last_index & found == false & validation == true) {
        mid_point = (first_index + last_index) / 2;

        try { //parses the date in the mid point index
            mid_point_parse = date_format.parse((String) all_dates.get(mid_point));
        } catch (ParseException e) {}

        if (mid_point_parse.equals(find_date_parse)) {
            found = true;

        } else if (mid_point_parse.after(find_date_parse)) {
            last_index = mid_point + 1;

        } else if (mid_point_parse.before(find_date_parse)) {

            first_index = mid_point - 1;

        }
    }
    return mid_point;
}
```

Comment: The array has to be sorted for a binary search.

Comment: @Devolus the array has been sorted, it won't find the element at the start of the array

Comment: If you change last instructions as following, what happens ?
last_index = mid_point + 1;  ==> last_index = mid_point - 1;
first_index = mid_point - 1;   ==> first_index = mid_point + 1;

Comment: @g.momo oh, that actually fixed it, thanks a lot.

Comment: The pleasure is mine. I have posted an answer, if you don't mind you could select it.

Comment: @g.momo thanks, i will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with bounds when you move your indexes.
Just change last instructions as followinng :

`last_index = mid_point + 1; ==> last_index = mid_point - 1;`

`first_index = mid_point - 1; ==> first_index = mid_point + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

changing the last instructions as following last_index = mid_point + 1; ==> last_index = mid_point - 1; first_index = mid_point - 1; ==> first_index = mid_point + 1;

fixed the issue, thanks g.momo

Comment: Okay, i insert an  answer

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check but I think you should change this:

```
        last_index = mid_point - 1;     

        
        first_index = mid_point + 1;
```